# addthis-button loses click-eventhandler after jquery clone()

Tags: jquery, clone, mouseclick-event, addthis

all

my problem is as follows:

I have a page containing an addthis-button. Normally, a click opens a small menu.

At some point, parts of this page - including the addthis-button - get cloned (via jQuery) and reused on the same page.

If I click on the cloned button, the menu doesn't open, and an addthis page is loaded.

So, apparently the eventhandler gets lost, and the button (which is really an <a>) reverts to being a link and displays the linked page.

So how can I re-register the events of the cloned button?

ETA: To clarify: I want to clone `addthis_button` complete with everything `addthis_widget.js` did to it.
`mylittlebutton` and its clickhandler `clickedhim()` are irrelevant for the problem, they only trigger the cloning of `addthis_button`.

I'd be grateful if some could point me in the right direction
Also, I have a 20-line snippet that illustrates this, if that helps.

Thank you

ETA:
the code snippet:

```
<script src='../../js/lib/jquery-1.6.2.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- up to here, the original button is initialized -->
<a class="addthis_button addthis_button" href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250">
  <img src="../../resources/img/button_share.gif" width="59" height="17" alt="Bookmark and Share" style="border:0"/>
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js"></script>


<br />

<!-- button to trigger the cloning -->
<input type="button" id="mylittlebutton" onclick="clickedhim(this);" value="CLICK ME" />

<script type="text/javascript" >
function clickedhim(eventtarget) {
  var nearest_addthis = $(eventtarget).siblings("a.addthis_button");
  // clone button, and insert it after the original
  nearest_addthis.after(nearest_addthis.clone());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I solved it.

According to the [Addthis Client API](http://www.addthis.com/help/client-api), any unsuspecting element can be turned into an addthis.button with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
addthis.button("#atbutton");
</script>
```

So, after I clone my elements, I call

```
addthis.button(".addthis_button");
```

and everything works like a charm.

Thank you all for your help.

**Addendum:** The above works to initialize the individual do-everything AddThis button.  If you have individual button controls such as Email, Facebook, etc..., you will need to use

`addthis.toolbox('<parent element>');`

to initialize those controls.

Answer (score 0):

the [clone documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) says `.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [,deepWithDataAndEvents]`. So you can pass 2 boolean parameters depending on your needs

so I think in the above example you want to do something like

```
var clone = $("a").clone(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.  Unfortunately,  `var clone = $("a").clone(true);`  and  `var clone = $("a").clone(true, true);`  have the same effect as before: the addthis pages is loaded.

Comment: can't you do something like `addthis.button(clone);`?

Comment: apparently the syntax is `elementToClone.clone()`...  I'll edit my original post to include my snippet so you can see what I'm doing.

Comment: this will not work because his event handlers are not attached using jQuery.

Comment: Good point. I think I'll ask on the official addthis forum. They should know the intricacies of their product

Answer (score 0):

Try using the delegate method: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ to attach the event to the button(s).

Comment: Interesting. Gimme a moment to try that

Comment: I've looked at it, and it seems that to delegate, I need to know the name of the handler, which I basically don't...  Maybe I'm looking at this from the wrong side. Maybe the solution is not to mess with the eventhandling directly, but rather to force the addthis-script to be executed once more for the cloned button?

Comment: Isn't the name of the handler 'clickedhim'?

Comment: that's the handler of `mylittlebutton`, which is only relevant for the simulation.  I want to clone `addthis_button` complete with everything addthis_widget.js did to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" class="mylittlebutton" value="CLICK ME" />

$('.mylittlebutton').live('click', clickedhim, { eventtarget: this });
```

You should also add some logic about handling your button ID when using clone()

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/UJ5JM/

Comment: I think we have a bit of a misunderstanding here :-) The snippet is just a small simulation, and `mylittlebutton` does nothing but to trigger the cloning process. The *real* problem becomes apparent if you click onto the newly-cloned button, *after* you clicked on `mylittlebutton`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UJ5JM/ I understand that you're doing more complicated logic with where the button is appended, but it should work the same.

Comment: `mylittlebutton` is irrelevant for this problem. `mylittlebutton`is only there to clone `.addthis_button`, and the problems are with the clone of `.addthis_button`. On another note, I didn't know jsfiddle. Thanks for enlightening me

Comment: so you want to clone the anchor tag when the button is clicked? I understand that mylittlebutton is irrelevant - I am just using it as a selector. http://jsfiddle.net/UJ5JM/1/

Comment: Yes, correctly. When the page loads, addthis_button is rendered, and after that, addthis_widget.js is applied to it, which apparently registers the handlers. After the cloning all of that is gone from the cloned button. That's my problem

Comment: Do you own addthis_widget.js ??

Comment: No, it's hosted at addthis, and minimized to boot.

Comment: Hmm.. quite the brick wall then, it seems like addthis_widget.js is binding it's event handlers only to elements that are currently on the document, so short of re-importing that script every time you clone an element I'm not sure what you could do. Perhaps try to contact the owners of this plugin and tell them about the wonders of live and delegate :P

Answer (score 0):

Following doc helped me.

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1337989-overview

I just have to add a class like following.

```
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
```